Flutter custom ThemeData Not Working in Release Mode
I am currently working on a Flutter project and I have defined a light theme in my app_theme.dart file as follows:
    final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  fontFamily: "Inter",
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
    background: AppColor.backgroundLight,
    onBackground: AppColor.black,
    primary: AppColor.primary,
    surface: AppColor.greyLight,
    inverseSurface: Colors.grey.shade400,
    inversePrimary: AppColor.black,
  ),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    titleLarge: const TextStyle().copyWith(
      fontSize: 24.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      color: AppColor.black,
    ),
    titleMedium: const TextStyle().copyWith(
      fontSize: 22.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      color: AppColor.black,
    ),
    
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
    errorMaxLines: 1,
    prefixIconColor: AppColor.greyStrong,
    suffixIconColor: AppColor.greyStrong,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13.h, horizontal: 16.w),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: AppColor.greyLight,
    hintStyle: const TextStyle().copyWith(
        fontSize: 12.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        color: AppColor.greyStrong,
        height: 1.0,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic
    ),
    labelStyle: const TextStyle().copyWith(
        fontSize: 12.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        color: AppColor.greyStrong,
        height: 1.0,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic
    ),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder().copyWith(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
    ),
    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder().copyWith(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
    ),
    focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder().copyWith(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppColor.primary, width: 1),
    ),
    errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder().copyWith(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppColor.red, width: 1.2),
    ),
    errorStyle: const TextStyle().copyWith(
      fontSize: 12.sp,
      color: AppColor.red,
    ),
  ),

  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

in MaterialApp Widget:
themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
theme: lightTheme,
issue:
The theme works perfectly fine in debug mode. However, when I build the app in release mode, the light theme does not seem to be applied correctly. The colors and styles
defined in the light theme are not reflected in the app when running in release mode.
I am using Flutter version (3.19.6) and Dart version (3.3.4)
What I have tried:

put:  in androidmanifest.xml
Defined as static in a class
used custom fonts (assets/fonts/)
flutter clean / flutter pub get
removed and added flutter again

Currently I am forced to write raw themes for every widgets, Although i have made reusable widgets in most cases, but that still does not make it easy
prior to flutter version 3.19.0 it was working perfectly fine in my projects.
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Please Share your main file where you applied the theme

The issue I was facing with the custom ThemeData not being applied correctly in release mode was due to the usage of the flutter_screenutil package. This package is designed to help manage different screen sizes and resolutions in Flutter apps, but it requires a specific setup when used in conjunction with custom themes.
In my case, the flutter_screenutil package needs to be initialized within the MaterialApp widget's builder method. This initialization should be done before defining the ThemeData instance. Here's how I did it:
    MaterialApp(
  ...
  builder: (ctx, child) {
    ScreenUtil.init(ctx);
    return Theme(
      data: lightTheme,
      child: HomePage(title: 'FlutterScreenUtil Demo'),
    );
  },
)

